# gnuplot conditional code explanation

Tags: linux, unix, gnuplot, gnu

I know that

```
gnuplot> p 'filename'
```

would plot the graph

I wanted to know how does this code exactly run

```
gnuplot> p 'filename' u 10:(($3==4 && $9==1000)?$13:1/0) w lp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it helps a bit to expand the abbreviated commands (you are taking these from someone else's script, I assume):

```
plot 'filename' using 10:(($3==4 && $9==1000) ? $13 : 1/0) with linespoints
```

That snippet is meant to plot the 10th vs. the 13th column from a big data file based on the values in the third and ninth columns.  The first argument to `using` is 10, so the value in the 10th column is the x coordinate of each point.  The y values are determined thus: if the value in the 3rd column is 4 and the value in the 9th column is 1000, the value from the 13th column is plotted; otherwise 1/0 (no value) is plotted.  That is done by the ternary operator `<condition> ? <operation if true> : <operation if false>`.

`with linespoints` means the points plotted will be connected by lines.